# error: The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    error: The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'?
```

I am trying to pass the user's login id from the loginWithEmailAndPasswords() method to homecontroller method(below method ) How I pass Data without Build context? i want to pass the user id to the second  homecontroller page(i already import the second homecontroller page in to first page),[image for my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZhF3.jpg)

```
import '../../../homecontroller.dart';
    class service{
     Future loginWithEmailAndPasswords(String email, String password) async {
                try {
                  UserCredential register = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                    Context context, email: email, password: password);
                  User registredUser = register.user;
            
                  if (await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('agent').doc(registredUser.uid) != null) {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                homecontroller(controllUserType: registredUser.uid)));
                  }
                  return registredUser.uid;
                } catch (e) {
                  print(e.toString());
                  return null;
                }
              }
        }
```

Here is my homecontroller Class this class is found on
the Second page and i import it on the first page

```
        class homecontroller extends StatelessWidget {
          final String controllUserType;
          const homecontroller({Key key,@required this.controllUserType}):super(key: key);
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            final Authservice auth=Provider.of(context).auth;
            return StreamBuilder(
                stream:auth.authStateChanges,
                  builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<String>snapshot){
                  if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.active){
                    final bool SignedIn=snapshot.hasData;
                    return SignedIn?HomePage(UserType:controllUserType):Adresspage();
                  }else{
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
        
                  },
            );
          }
        }
```

I Already Accept a BuildContext as a parameter in the loginWithEmailAndPasswords method (Above method) &  I pass the 'context' from where you call loginWithEmailAndPasswords. I Pass the Context on Below Method but I still get An Error, error: The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'?

here is my method where I pass Context to the loginWithEmailAndPasswords method (Above method)

```
switch (authFormType) {
          case AuthFormType.SignIn:
         if(   await auth.loginWithEmailAndPasswords(_email, _password , context)!=null)
            {

              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');
              // Navigator.push(context,
              //     MaterialPageRoute(
              //         builder: (context)=>homecontroller(controllUserType:_dropDownValue)
              //     )
              // );
            }else{
           setState(() {
             _warrning = 'wrong email and password combinations';
           });
         }}
```

Comment: >Future loginWithEmailAndPasswords(Context context, String email, String password) async {.... }

Comment: Aceept a BuildContext as a parameter in loginWithEmailAndPasswords & pass the 'context' from where you call loginWithEmailAndPasswords.